# count items up onclick by class name

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I want to create an eshop basket.. so i want to count items up when i press a buy button. I tried to use getElementById and simple call the name of id in my basket.

--

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var index = 0;
</script>
```

somewhere in the top -----

```
<div>items :<input type="text" id="tb" style="width: 20px; color:green; font-weight:bold; border:none; background: none; margin-left:20px;"/></div>
```

and when i press the buy button -------

```
<input  name="button" type="submit" value="add to basket" onClick="index = index + 1;document.getElementById('tb').value = index;" />
```

so this is worked .. but know i want to duplicate the basket and have it twice in the page ( in the top and in the end ) so if i tried to call again the same id it just don't work (cause the uniqueness of id). I suppose i should use classname istead but i don't know how ..

I'm more than new to js hoping for a solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could duplicate `document.getElementById('tb').value = index` and use a second (unique) id. Or you iterate over `documnet.getElementsByName('elementsname')`, but your `input` would have to have a `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class instead of id:

```
<div>items :<input type="text" class="tb" style="width: 20px; color:green; font-weight:bold; border:none; background: none; margin-left:20px;"/></div>
```

Then iterate over the items that have that class:

```
function tb_increment() {
    index++;
    tbs = document.getElementsByClassName("tb");
    for (var i = 0; i < tbs.length; i++) {
        tbs[i].value = index;
    }
}
```

Then use this function in your click handler:

```
<input  name="button" type="submit" value="add to basket" onClick="tb_increment();" />
```

Answer (score -1):

try this sample code pattern:

```
$(".class").each(function(){ index++; });
$("#tb").val(index);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. He wants to put index in multiple places.